# how to use a hidden field for multiple form submition

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a form that i want to filled up by the end user in few steps.
in the first step i want to let them fill Name,Address,Mobile number.
And when click next button i want to appear another part of the form to fill the other details such as upload a image .
i did research online,i found 2 articles useful,
One thing is about sessions and the other thing is about hidden fields.
In my opinion i think sessions are not a good way to use for form submitting.Because some browsers are might have disabled sessions.
So ill go with hidden fields.

In my database i have a unique id which is auto increment.What i want to do is to let user to submit a form.In the first step i want them to submit their name,addres,mobile number(In this time it is inserting data to the database- Only for couple of columns.) And in my database i have a field for upload a image.In the first step it gets a null value.I want to update that null value in the next step by getting a that id from the first step

Please give me the basic idea to start this.A little help much appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply use a input tag with type=hidden it will not display on your form and you can use this like normal input type=text.

Comment: And how do i get the id ? which ID should i get to upload the image in next page ? im thinking about update the record in next page.So i have to use the id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:-

You can add a class on the input which you want to hide

```
<input type="text" name="example" class="inputHidden">
```

after that add style in your page like this

```
<style>
.inputHidden{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: And how do i get the id ? which ID should i get to upload the image in next page ? im thinking about update the record in next page.So i have to use the id ?

Comment: yes you can update the record on next page, when you insert in your database there is function mysql_insert_id() which gives the last inserted id in the database

Comment: But it may be vary,Because some people write fast, some are not.So in this case people should have uploaded image in to others inserted datas.

Comment: yes some user write fast and some slow but he id which the above function returns will be same for the user and u can save that in a variable after inserting the query and when u update the row u can use that id.

Comment: I got it,can you please give me a little example in php about that ? Im new to this.

Comment: after inserting the first page data u can get the id from the function u can save that in one of the hidden field and when u submit the second page data u can use that id in your update query...

Comment: if you got the point pls mark my answer and close the question

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to place the form data into new, hidden inputs - take the initial input.

```
<input type="text" name="example">
```

On the next page add a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="exampleP2" value="<?php echo $_POST['example']; ?>">
```

Comment: It should be noted that you should try to not use $_ data directly wherever possible; instead, get the data into a variable, validate it, sanitize it, and then use the variable.

Comment: In my database i have a unique id which is auto increment.What i want to do is to let user to submit a form.In the first step i want them to submit their name,addres,mobile number(In this time it is inserting data to the database- Only for couple of columns.) And in my database i have a field for upload a image.In the first step it gets a null value.I want to update that null value in the next step by getting a that id from the first step

Answer (score 0):

You can get form submited data and use it in input hidden fileds
for e.g. in first form you have 
name ,email etc fields
in other form you have more fields
here you can use `<input type="hidden" name ="firstname">`
and thus you can add as many as you want